# Как прервать выполнение скриптов на стороннем сайте? (Автоматизация браузера)

Tags: javascript, браузер

мы выполняем парсинг данных с одного большого сайта. На данном сайте придумали антифрод систему, которая начала грузить процессор при работе в многопотоке.

После загрузки страницы начинают выполняться JS скрипты, которые грузят процессор сильно, на протяжении примерно 40 секунд. Если заблокировать React перед открытием страницы, нагрузки нет, но и проникнуть в тело сайта не выходит.

Скажите, можно ли каким-то образом прерывать выполнение всех скриптов на странице, после ее успешной загрузки? Чтобы этот цикл, который грузит процессор прерывался/завершался?

Comment: у вас не хватает инфы о том чем вы парсите все это дело и тд. Здесь силениум или что